# Get a Color from a position in my form in C#

Tags: c#, colors

How is it possible that I can read the color code at a certain position in my application? (Red circle)

And that I can then output the values in the `richtextbox`?

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Give this a try
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120665/determine-color-of-a-pixel-in-a-winforms-application

Answer (score 0):

You can grab color of a pixel using GetPixel function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr window);
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr dc, int x, int y);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr window, IntPtr dc);

public static Color GetColorAt(int x,  int y)
{
    IntPtr desk = GetDesktopWindow();
    IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(desk);
    int a = (int) GetPixel(dc, x, y);
    ReleaseDC(desk, dc);
    return Color.FromArgb(255, (a >> 0) & 0xff, (a >> 8) & 0xff, (a >> 16) & 0xff);
}
```

Comment: How i can add this Value to my Textbox?

Comment: textBox.Text = GetColorAt(x,y).ToString()

Comment: Okay i have testing this i get this error Message"The name is not available in the context "

Comment: check your textBox name, may be it like textBox1 actually

Comment: i have add folowing Code: `textBox1.Text = GetColorAt(x, y).ToString();` and I still get the error message

Comment: try test it with any numbers (for example 1,1) instead of x, y