# C# How to get pixel color/data from the screen?

Tags: c#, colors, screen, pixel

Ok so I'm trying to get a little more advanced here and one of the things i want to learn how to do is get pixel color or data from a certain position on the screen. I have searched a lot but it seems most people want to do this in c or c++.

Im making a program that scans a location on the screen for a certain color. If that location contains anything with orange then the number in my window turns into a 1 for true or 0 for false.
The background of my window is transparent, if that matters at all.

I have only come across Graphics.CopyFromScreen() and bitmap.GetPixel();

Thanks

Comment: Does this help:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483928/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel

Comment: Wow thanks i couldn't find that before. Although i was afraid i would come across the old [DLLImport] user32.dll thing again. i hate messing with those native win32 functions because its far more advanced that i would like to go, but thanks, ill give a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture specific rectangle form the screen use the following code

```
    public Bitmap CaptureFromScreen(Rectangle rect)
    {
        Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = null;

        if (rect == Rectangle.Empty)//capture the whole screen
        {
            rect = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        }

        bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(rect.Width,rect.Height);

        Graphics p = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture);


            p.CopyFromScreen(rect.X,
                     rect.Y,
                     0, 0,
                     rect.Size,
                     CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);


        p.Dispose();

        return bmpScreenCapture;
    }
```

To Get The color form a specific location use the function

```
    public Color GetColorFromScreen(Point p)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(p, new Size(2, 2));

        Bitmap map = CaptureFromScreen(rect);

        Color c = map.GetPixel(0, 0);

        map.Dispose();

        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Im still testing things out to see what will work and what won't. Thanks, ill give this a try too.

Comment: Why the duplicated code? Just check if the rectangle is empty and if so assign the screens rectangle to it. Then you can just use the 'just the  rectangle' sections.

Comment: @JamesCoyle Thanks, I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following reference, I think this is what you need:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24850/Geting-pixel-color-from-screen-shoot-image