# C# getting various stuff from the position of the mouse cursor

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it was possible to get the color at the position of the mouse cursor (something like a color picker). While the program is running it should get the mouse cursor position and the color at that same position on the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read the Color of a Screen Pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483928/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel)

Comment: Which client-side technology are you using?

Comment: @JimG. that actually can be the right solution, i don't have a computer rn to test it but ill check and will get back to you. I'm using c# with a browser for the current example. You know of a good online compiler that can give me an executable ? :) (but not visual studio xD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what you want:

First use:

[Mouse.Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then use

[Bitmap.GetPixel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.110).aspx)

and give it X and Y from the mouse position.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483928/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel) a question with code examples.

Comment: `Bitmap.GetPixel` is completely inappropriate here, unless you are taking a screenshot of the entire screen at some interval, storing it in the bitmap, and getting the pixel color.

Comment: @RonBeyer You're inappropriate. Try to document yourself if you're going to make a critic. That's how you do it in C#. Screenshot and pixel color.

Added some more to help the guy

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a form.

Say we have a pictureBox docked to fill the entire form.

We can use the MouseClick event of the pictureBox Control to get the position of the mouse.

Then cast the image of the `pictureBox` to Bitmap Then Call `GetPixel()` on it which returns a color, then `.Name` on it.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    MessageBox.Show(bit.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).Name);
}
```

Comment: This would work if i had a picturebox, i need my program to run somewhat in the background and get the colors from the screen not from a picturebox

Comment: Well i used `picturebox` to explain it to you, it's all about the `Bitmap `