# c# color extractor frequently returning white

Tags: c#, colors, pixel

I have a program that has a small graphics portion to it, where you can look at and store the color of specific pixels of the screen.

The problem is that when I extract color, sometimes I get the color I want... sometimes I just get White, or some other random color (usually white, but I'm also using a white background to test with).

Can you spot any reason why that would be?  I'm also totally open to possible improvements.

I have a picturebox called Canvas, and I can either click "Capture Image" which does a screenshot as follows:

```
    private void CaptureImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
        Canvas.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        Canvas.Image = bitmap;
        graphics.Dispose();
        this.Visible = true;
    }
```

Or I can load an image file, though for this test I'm just doing the capture.

When I right-click somewhere on the image, in my mousedown event I do:

```
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            pointPoint = e.Location;
            Debug.WriteLine("right mouse: " + e.Location.ToString());
            ContextMenuStrip cm = new ContextMenuStrip();
            cm.Items.Add("Flag this as Point");
            cm.Items.Add("Extract Color");
            Canvas.ContextMenuStrip = cm;
            cm.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(Cm2Click);
        }
```

(pointPoint is a Point object)

As you can see, I verify the location where I clicked using the debug window.  In my context menu, I also verify it again to make sure it didn't change before getting called.  The context menu does:

```
   private void Cm2Click(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var clickedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem;
        ToolStripItem menuText = e.ClickedItem;
        Debug.WriteLine(menuText);
        if (menuText.ToString() == "Extract Color")
        {
            string input = "Default";
            bool testBox = false;
            do
            {
                if (InputBox.inputBox("ColorName", "You must provide a unique name for this color", ref input) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) && input != "Default")
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("location changed to: " + pointPoint);
                        colorExtractor = Functions.GetColorAt(pointPoint);
                        ColorData clr = new ColorData(input, colorExtractor);
                        string expression;
                        expression = $"Name = '{clr.Name}'";
                        DataRow[] foundRows;
                        DataTable dt = _allEventData.Tables["ColorData"];
                        foundRows = dt.Select(expression);
                        if (foundRows.Length > 0) {
                            testBox = false;
                            Debug.WriteLine("Color Found");
                        }
                        else {
                            dt.Rows.Add(clr.Name, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B);
                            dt.AcceptChanges();
                            testBox = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    return;
                }
            } while (testBox == false);
        }
    }
```

and ColorData is just a class I defined to help store data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace EventClicker
{
    public class ColorData : EventArgs

    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int R { get; set; }
        public int G { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public bool Found { get; set; }

        public ColorData(String name, Color color)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.R = color.R;
            this.G = color.G;
            this.B = color.B;
        }

        public ColorData(String name, String r, String g, String b)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.R = Int32.Parse(r);
            this.G = Int32.Parse(g);
            this.B = Int32.Parse(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least, the method I call (Functions.GetColorAt) is defined here (and I definitely stole this from someone on the web) Edit: That somewhere is here, [How to read the Color of a Screen Pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483928/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EventClicker
{
    public static class Functions
    {

        private static Bitmap screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, int dwRop);

        public static Color GetColorAt(Point location)
        {
            using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
            {
                using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
                    IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
                    int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, 1, 1, hSrcDC, location.X, location.Y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                    gdest.ReleaseHdc();
                    gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
                }
            }

            return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that `screenPixel` is a static variable, instead of being a local variable inside the method `Functions.GetColorAt`?

Comment: Just that I don't know what I'm doing :D

Comment: I went ahead and made that change.  Didn't fix the problem, but does make me a little bit less crazy regarding static variables.

Comment: I would try to isolate the pixel-reading problem, removing all unrelated code like updating DataTable rows etc. I would fill a PictureBox with the color, to have a visual clue about what's going on while moving the mouse. If I was still confused then I would try capturing a bigger portion of the screen, something like 50x50, and display it in the PictureBox.

Comment: The pixels get grabbed just fine. Maybe you pick up antialiased pixels which look pretty random, esp. around text. Maybe the rightclick brings up a menue?

Comment: `ColorData : EventArgs` Huh? Why do you inherit from that? This is quite confusing; `EventArgs` class has no fields and you better create a new class..

Comment: @TaW that's a relic I can probably remove.  At one time, I was only building my dataset in one window passing the data back to that window, and I had to pass it using eventargs... it was bad.

Comment: That graphics.fromhwnd(intptr.zero) statement... is that looking at my window or the desktop?  Because it should be looking in my window... that may be the problem if it's not.

Comment: It looks at the desktop and you will need to feed in desktop coordinates. You can either use `Point p = Control.MousePosition;` or convert via `PointToScreen` and `PointToClient`

Comment: I need to not do graphics.fromhwnd then.  I don't want it to read from the desktop.

Comment: I want it to read from an image I have loaded to canvas.image

Comment: To read from a bitmap bmp you can/should simply use bmp.GetPixel, maybe in the mousemove of the picturebox/control that show the image. do mind that picturebox may scale the image and the mouse coordinates will know nothing about this, so you need to scale them as well..

Comment: Awesome.  That worked perfectly, ty.